# Masking Layer leads for error InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [128,0] vs. [128,6] in Keras

Tags: keras, recurrent-neural-network, masking, named-entity-recognition, crf

My model is as below.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=wordEmbeddings.shape[0]+2, output_dim=wordEmbeddings.shape[1], input_length=n_in,  trainable=False))       
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0.))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(200, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.5, dropout=0.5, name='bilstm1')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(100, activation="relu")))
crf = CRF(n_out,sparse_target=True)
model.add(crf)
```

Model Summary

[image]
When I was using this model without masking layer this model works fine. But loss was negative. So as a solution for that I tried to add masking and then I got this error saying

> Blockquote[image]

Answer (score 0):

From your description, first thing is you should use input_dim=wordEmbeddings.shape[0]+1 instead of +2, in the documentation it's saying that you should use max_index + 2, but max_index = shape[0] - 1, so you should use +1 instead of +2. Then you just pass all 0 to the first row of wordEmbeddings weights, and your pre-trained embedding to the rest.

Comment: I tried that too. But didn't work. Any other suggestions? I am getting good results when I predict the test data even though the loss is minus. Do I still need to make the loss positive?

Comment: the loss can be negative, it's not a problem, especially for probability layer, the loss can be e.g. negative log prob. I suggest you to make a toy dataset example, and provide an example I can replicate. In the code you provided, the compile part is also missing, so please provide a runnable example.

Comment: Thank you very much I will check.